# Is accessing DataRowCollection.Count O(1) or O(n) on DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, collections, datatable

More, is there a reference on the perf characteristic of those things? I see that MSDN tells what it does, but rarely how it is done/what are the speed guarantees.

The precise structure I mention is [datarowcollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx).

Comment: Well, seems easy enough to test.  Time how long it takes for a collection of size 1, and for a collection of size 1,000,000.  (Obviously you'll need millions of calls averaged together to have it mean anything.)  If they're about the same it's clearly O(1), if the larger data set takes longer, it's not O(1).  That said, I'm reasonably confidant that it's O(1).

Comment: I wonder if there is not some sort of convention in c# where Count() might be O(n) and Count would be O(1).

Comment: Well, a property, by design, shouldn't do a lot of complex calculatins, it should just be quickly returning a value, so having a property be O(n) would violate convention.  That said, there are `Count()` methods that are O(1), and they violate no conventions at all.

Comment: @Guffa sums it up pretty well. You could always use Reflector or something too look at the code yourself too if you really what to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Count` property is O(1), because the count is stored in the class, it's not found out by actually counting the records.

You are right that the documentation doesn't contain much information about performance for that class, you will find more performance information for the `List<T>` class for example. You would generally see to what the property or method is doing, to determine the performance characteristics.

One hint in this case is that `Count` is a property, which usually means that it's an O(1) operation. As a comparison, `IEnumerable<T>.Count` is a method instead of a property, because it loops through the items to count them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fairer to say that IEnumerable<T>.Count() MIGHT be O(N), as it surely isn't when the underlying implementation is List<T>; point being that a client of IEnumerable<T> cannot rely on Count() being performant.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: It's true that the `Count` method has optimisations for some collections, but that's beyond this example.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if one could determine automatically where to change the representation. Some static analysis folks are surely looking at this, althiugh I would not know where to look.